# macOS Monterey stuck at progress 2 hours. Is this normal?

Tags: monterey

I am trying to upgrade to macOS Monterey when suddenly it seems to not progress anymore. Below is the screenshot.
[image]
It does seem to be stuck at 2 hours and 37 minutes. Is this normal?

Comment: What model of Mac are you updating? If you were able to take a screenshot, then I'd say the installation isn't proceeding very far.

Comment: What previous macOS are you updating from? Handy tip before any macOS system upgrade, after a full TimeMachine backup: 1| Boot into [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac) to clear out any system caches, then reboot. 2| Boot into [Single User mode](https://osxdaily.com/2013/08/07/how-to-repair-a-mac-disk-with-fsck-from-single-user-mode/) (Cmd-S) to run a disk check. Lastly - if you are updating from a much older macOS to Monterey, (v10.11, v10.12, for example,) you may need to make incremental upgrades to 'work your way up', so to speak.